# Find a way to manage my project's sub directories

Tags: git

I have a requirement of my project,

```
project/
  .git/
  project-app/
  assets/
  plug-ins/
    paypal-plugin/
    tc-plugin/
```

I use the git to manage the versions of my `project`, and under my `project/plug-ins/` directory there have several plug-in directory. 
I want to use other git to manage everyone itself(every plugin have itself's own git).

In GitHub I saw a [project](https://github.com/openstack/openstack):

under the there openstack/ directory, there have many like `adjutant @ 571aa70`, I guess this can achieve my requirement.

but how to do in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you should consider [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Git submodules allow you configure one or more "sub-repos" in the way you describe.

However, an alternative would be to consider using a dependency manager such as npm (node.js), cargo (rust), or maven (java). Dependency managers are a powerful way to include dependencies (aka, separate projects or libraries) in your project.

There are pros and cons to each, but both of them enable you to manage the sub-folders independently of your primary project.